# Problem with running Django 1.1.1 on Google App Engine Developement Server

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I've downloaded google_appengine version 1.3.1. Using some web tutorials, I've created basic django 1.1.1 application. Using appcfg I managed to deploy it on GAE and it works. The problem is, that application doesn't want to work on dev_appengine.py developement server.

Whenever I run the app GAE local server is returning HTTP 200 without any content. If I set basic environement and run main.py manually, then the page is properly returned on stdout.

I've also created very basic helloworld application, and this one is working ok on the devel server.

Do you have any idea, how can I debug the devel server? Option -d doesn't give any usefull insight at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had module nammed same way as the default GAE launcher (main/ and main.py). After renaming the launcher everything works great.